# vcpkg: qtdeclarative-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz "Transferred partial file"

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, package, vcpkg

I try installing QT5 using vcpkg on Windows 10. Unfortunately, when executing `./vcpkg.exe install qt5:x64-windows`, I get a long list of errors, must useful information being:

```
-- Downloading http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.15/5.15.0/submodules/qtdeclarative-everywhere-src-5.15.0.tar.xz... Failed. Status: 18;"Transferred a partial file"
```

---

```
Failed to download file.
If you use a proxy, please set the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment
variables to "https://user:password@your-proxy-ip-address:port/".
Otherwise, please submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues
```

---

```
Error: Building package qt5-declarative:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest portfiles with `.\vcpkg update`, then
submit an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues including:
  Package: qt5-declarative:x64-windows
  Vcpkg version: 2020.06.15-nohash
```

As I am using the current version and was successful downloading and installing opencv as well as eigen3, I don't think proxy is being an issue.

I was able to download the file itself and hoped, I could manually paste it at the required position in the code (is this possible?) or use a different mirror. I would be glad if someone could give me guydance, as I am new to vcpkg.

Thanks in advance

---

Edit: As suggested by @drescherjm, I pasted the file in the `vcpkg\downloads` folder. Now I am looking at the `File does not have expected hash` error. How do I solve that issue?

Comment: If you can download the exact same file, put the file in the `vcpkg\downloads` folder. If it is not the exact file the hash code won't match.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm. Now I get a `File does not have expected hash` error, just like you described. How do I change the hash code of the tar.xz file?